Different results when only test dataset is loaded using `keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory`
I used the following lines to fetch my test dataset:
test_ds = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(img_path, image_size=image_size, batch_size = batch_size)

When I run my model on this, I get the following stats: Accuracy = 0.5214362272240086, Precision = 0.5950113378684807, F1-score = 0.5434962717481359
However, when I load my dataset in this way:
_, new_images = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(img_path, shuffle=True, subset="both", seed=1, validation_split=0.9999, image_size=image_size, batch_size = batch_size)

The performance stats are: Accuracy = 0.9635388739946381, Precision = 0.9658291457286432, F1-score = 0.96875
Why would this be happening? Any similar experience?
Edit- code to get the above metrics:
predict = model.predict(new_images)
actual = tf.concat([y for x, y in new_images], axis=0).numpy().tolist()

# Get optimal threshold
fpr, tpr, thresholds = sklearn.metrics.roc_curve(actual, predict)

# Youden's index
J = tpr - fpr

# Optimal threshold
threshold = thresholds[np.argmax(J)]

# Use threshold
predicted = [1 if res > threshold else 0 for res in predict]

# Metrics
print(sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(actual, predicted), sklearn.metrics.f1_score(actual, predicted), sklearn.metrics.precision_score(actual, predicted)


Are you talking about a model.evaluate(..) call or actual training? It's not really clear for me what "run the model on this" does.

@mhenning I did not use model.evaluate, rather used raw probabilities to find the optimal cutoff using ROC, but you can think of it that way...

Can you show the code where you got the metrics?

The reason why you get so different results is because in test_ds, the dataset gets treated as a training set and therefore gets shuffled everytime the dataset gets iterated. In new_images, the dataset is explicitly retrieved as a validation set and is only shuffled once, and then never again.
So when you call
predict = model.predict(new_images)
actual = tf.concat([y for x, y in new_images], axis=0).numpy().tolist()

the dataset gets iterated through two times: one time with the predict call, and one time with the actual call. For the new_images dataset, you get the same order for both calls. But for the test_ds dataset, you get a different order of samples for predict and actual, and with it a labeling missmatch. This explains the bad accuracy.

I tested it with the following piece of code. You need an image folder for that, I don't know how to mock that (I had 13 images in there):
df = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    r'path//to//images',
    labels=list(range(13)), #  mock labels, every image has another label
    shuffle=True, seed=1
)
_, df2 = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    r'path//to//images',
    labels=list(range(13)), #  mock labels, every image has another label
    shuffle=True, seed=1,
    subset='both', validation_split=.999
)
print([x[1] for x in df][0].numpy())
# prints: [ 7  5  8  0 11  1  4  6  3  2 10  9 12]
print([x[1] for x in df][0].numpy())
# prints: [ 8  9  6  0  7 12 10  5  4  3  2  1 11]
print([x[1] for x in df2][0].numpy())
# prints: [ 3  4 10  1  6  0  7 12  9  8 11  5]
print([x[1] for x in df2][0].numpy())
# prints: [ 3  4 10  1  6  0  7 12  9  8 11  5]

Note how the label order changes for 2 calls for df, but not for df2. That means, the predictions and labels in your examples would be different images in test_ds. The seed only fixes the order of (different) randomizings for test_ds, so you'll always get [ 7  5  8...] first and [ 8  9  6..] second for this example.
(PS: This is a good example why more than one line of code in the question is mostly a good idea, otherwise I would not have come up with the solution ;) )

This is it! Thanks a ton for guiding me through this :)
